# Why is failbit set when I enter EOF?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, operating-system, iostream

I'm currently learning how `while (cin >> num)` work and I found out that there are two steps.
First one is the operator>> function return a istream object with error state, and the second is bool converter that convert istream object into bool depend on its state.

But I find it confusing that in the bool convert function, it will return 0 only if failbit or badbit is set. And the operator>> function will set eofbit if it read EOF.

bool convert function: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/

operator>> function: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

In this case, After I enter EOF the bool converter should return 1 because the failbit and badbit aren't set.

Therefore, I use the below program to check what actually happened to the error bit after I enter EOF. **And I find out that the failbit will be set after entering EOF!!**

So I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand why is failbit set?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    cout << cin.eof() << " " << cin.fail() << " " << cin.bad() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input: ^Z(on windows using qt creator, non qt c++ project)
Output: 1 1 0

Input: ^D(on windows using qt creator, non qt c++ project)
Output: 0 1 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eofbit` is set when a read operation encounters EOF while reading data into the stream's buffer.  The data hasn't been processed yet.

`failbit` is set when the requested data fails to be extracted from the buffer, such as when reading an integer with `operator>>`. While waiting for digits to arrive, EOF could occur. `eofbit` alone is not enough to enter an error state, as there may be usable data in the buffer.

So, for example, imagine a `while (cin >> num)` loop is used and the user enters `123<Ctrl-Z>`.

- on the 1st iteration, `operator>>` reads `1`, `2`, `3` into the buffer, then encounters Ctrl-Z, so it sets `eofbit` and stops reading. `123` is then extracted from the buffer into  `num` and the operator exits. At this point, the stream is not yet in an error state. When the stream's `bool` conversion is evaluated by `while`, it returns true, allowing the `while` body to be entered so it can process `num`.
- on the next iteration, `operator>>` sees `eofbit` is set, preventing further reading. There is nothing left in the buffer to extract into `num`, so the operator sets `failbit` and exits. The stream is now in an error state. When the stream's `bool` conversion is evaluated by `while`, it returns false, breaking the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your explanation is very clear!! I always thought it is because of EOF that terminate the program. Didn't know that either char or double can have the same effect too~

Comment: BTW Do you know what is Ctrl+D means in windows? If I press Crtl+D it will only set failbit, and all I can find on the internet only talks about what Crtl+D do in unix-based os.

Comment: @Benasking7124 `Ctrl+D` doesn't really do anything in a Windows `cmd` window, it is treated as a control character (`^D`).  It does something in the context of other apps, though (ie, in Explorer, it moved the selected file to the Recycle Bin)

Comment: Oh I see!! It's because the character `^D` isn't accepted by int type that trigger the failbit right?(just like if  I enter "abc" into an int variable) Not because there is some special meaning of `Crtl+D`

Comment: @Benasking7124 yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

If the EOF is the *first* input, the `operator>>` fails to read an integer, so the stream enters the `fail()` state.

If you type at least one digit before the Ctrl-Z, that digit is read and the input succeeds.